# My h1 and h2 element gets hidden behind section when I use skeleton-css-boilerplate

Tags: css, html, flexslider, skeleton-css-boilerplate

This is my first time using skeleton css. I have a header element and a section element. The header element contains an h1 and h2 element. my section has an slider where I have used flexslider. Now whenever I try to resize the browser, the slider collapses with the header and hides the lower portion of it.

```
<header class="sixteen columns">
<h1>Infinite Jest Online Judge</h1>
<h2>"This is for everyone" - Sir Tim Berners Lee</h2>
```

```
<section class="ten columns slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/pic-1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/pic-2.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is the code of my header and section

Comment: Code? Example? Anything? Hard to fix a code problem _with no code_.

Comment: I am sorry, i am adding it right now.

Comment: I have added the code, @Kyle Sevenoaks. Does skeleton css resize the font size of the elements when the window gets smaller or does it just add margin. In my case its doing nothing

Comment: Should I add anything else? @KyleSevenoaks